# Error while converting String to datetime in Java 8

Tags: datetime, java-8

I am trying to convert the String to LocalDateTime object in java 8. Below is my code.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args){

            String text = "27/11/2016 11:10 pm";
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"));

            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }
```

and below is the error I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '27/11/2016 11:10 pm' could not be parsed at index 17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String text = "27/11/2016 11:10 PM";`

it has to be in capital letters.

Comment: It works. But I am getting i/p from the bootstrap datepicker and there it is like am/pm only.

Comment: cant you convert it to uppercase before sending the value to the parse method? can you give me the real example? thnx

Comment: @anything convert it to uppercase before calling parse.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Or use a case insensitive formatter...

Answer (score 0):

You need capital letters for `am/pm`.

```
String text = "27/11/2016 11:10 PM";
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"));
```

a       am-pm-of-day                text              PM

[see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)